# How to compare actual String instead of comparing backing array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

`String.equals()` method in Java compares the backing arrays of two strings. So if the arrays are of different size same strings would not be equal.

Example:

```
char[] in = new char[50];
in[0] = 'K';
in[1] = 's';
in[2] = 'h';
in[3] = 'i';
in[4] = 't';
in[5] = 'i';
in[6] = 'z';
String s = new String(in);
System.out.println(s.equals("Kshitiz"));
```

Output:

> false

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't but you need to when getting text as char[] from an API.

Comment: There are many ways to create a string from chars. If you want to pass an array, you should at least make it the right size. And `char` arrays are just like `char` values, they're not convenient and should rarely be used.

Comment: If the API returns a 50-long char array for a string of 7 chars, then the API is seriously f* up. Why would any sane API do that?

Comment: When getting char[] from an API method, making it a particular size isn't under my control.

Comment: @JBNizet Beats me...

Comment: It's all about creating a `String` from a null-terminated `char`-array. Has nothing to do with comparing strings. You should really change your question title!

Comment: @isnot2bad OP didn't know what was really the way to solve his problem. His title is relevant to the way he thought was the best when asking.

Comment: @dystroy I agree. But now he knows and the title doesn't make any sense now. Nevertheless, question is already closed.

Comment: @dystroy That's right. That's why I'm not editing the title. Someone else thinking along the same lines is likely to find this more useful and google for  similar terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be creating strings that don't hold what they should hold. Using a hack like `trim` to deal with bad objects is a bad practice.

Assuming you can't fix the API giving you badly sized char arrays, just count the not null chars **before** creating the string.

```
    char[] in = new char[50];
    in[0] = 'K';
    in[1] = 's';
    in[2] = 'h';
    in[3] = 'i';
    in[4] = 't';
    in[5] = 'i';
    in[6] = 'z';
    int length = 0;
    while (length<in.length && in[length]!=(char)0) length++;
    String s = new String(in, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added one more code line to your code to show what happen here.

```
    char[] in = new char[50];
    in[0] = 'K';
    in[1] = 's';
    in[2] = 'h';
    in[3] = 'i';
    in[4] = 't';
    in[5] = 'i';
    in[6] = 'z';
    String s = new String(in);
    System.out.println(s.equals("Kshitiz"));
    //just use following
    System.out.println(s);
```

Now run this code. you can see `s` having `\u0000` char just after `Kshitiz`

Comment: Not empty characters that would be space it's ASCII 0 or null.

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` returns `false` because the two strings are not the same.

If you actually print the original string, then you will see the difference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] in = new char[50];
    in[0] = 'K';
    in[1] = 's';
    in[2] = 'h';
    in[3] = 'i';
    in[4] = 't';
    in[5] = 'i';
    in[6] = 'z';
    String s = new String(in);
    System.out.println(s.equals("Kshitiz"));
    System.out.println(s+ "X"); // new line
}
```

O/P :

```
false
Kshitiz                                X
```

You can see that the two strings are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Java's Strings are not null-terminated.

If you create Strings from a byte or character buffer, use a constructor that lets you specify the length.

```
new String(bytes, 0, 7, "ASCII");
new String(characters, 0, 7);
```

Comment: This would only work in this case. `trim()` is the way to go if you get char[] from somewhere else.

Comment: trim() also throws away stuff from the beginning. And spaces and tabs from the end. If someone gives you raw bytes or characters, they will also give you the length. Or have it null-terminated. You could then search for the 0 byte.